# Facade mock called twice not overriding first?

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, mocking

I am using Laravel and mocking a Facade object like

```
Confide::shouldReceive('user')->atLeast(1)->andReturn( (object) array('id' => 42) );
var_dump(Confide::user()->id); // returns int(42)
Confide::shouldReceive('user')->atLeast(1)->andReturn( (object) array('id' => 1) );
var_dump(Confide::user()->id); // returns int(42) but should be int(1)
```

However `var_dump(Confide::user()->id);` always returns 42. Even though the second one should return `1` as I set it to `1`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Confide::shouldReceive('user')->atLeast(1)->andReturn(
    (object) array('id' => 42),
    (object) array('id' => 1)
);
```

So this will have to be run at least once.

The first call will return an object with `id = 42`, the second and any subsequent will return an object with `id = 1`.

PS: I have never worked with mockery, I just checked its documentation http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/expectations.html

Comment: Is there anyway to have it return a different value after the 3rd call? It get's called a lot.

Comment: @Steven check the syntax that accepts an anonymous function: `andReturnUsing(closure, ...)` on the provided documentation page. That way you can create your own counter (or some other shared variable) and return whatever you need depending on its value. Alternatively you can use `andReturnValues()` and prepare the array with `0..3` indexes.

Comment: Im just trying to figure out why calling it again doesnt set a new value. I dont really like the idea of hard coding a number of times a method gets called.

Comment: @Steven: "why calling it again doesnt set a new value" --- because of this https://github.com/padraic/mockery/issues/401. Found it using "mockery shouldReceive override" google request

Comment: @Steven "I dont really like the idea of hard coding a number of times a method gets called" --- I don't see anything wrong with it. It actually is a sign, that your test case probably is doing too much.